# Encryption and Decryption of data in MySQL and Codeigniter project

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

Earlier I was storing data in Database without Encrypting. But Now i need to Encrypt both the existing data as well as newly inserted data.

So here What i did:
For encryption of existing data I used  AES_ENCRYPT() method ,

Update `table` SET `poster_id` = AES_ENCRYPT('poster','Mykey') ;

It is working fine and i am able to DECRYPT data using AES_DECRYPT() method .

In code i have done changes as :

$config['encryption_key'] = 'Mykey'; //in config.php page.

and encrypted value using

$encrypted_string = $this->encrypt->encode($poster_id);

This is also working fine as i am able to ENCRYPT NEW inserting data to database.

But when i am trying to DECRYPT all the data now by using AES_DECRYPT() function (both existing and newly inserted data ).I am getting correct value for old data and getting Null value for the newly inserted data .
Please suggest on this or give any alternative solution.

Thank You.

Comment: Your new PHP-based encryption doesn't work. Hard to tell why, though, seeing as you've not posted any actual code.

Comment: `AES_DECRYPT` returns `NULL` if it detects invalid data. It sounds like codeigniter generated a bad encryption

Comment: Why do you think `$this->encrypt->encode()` is identical to mysql's `AES_ENCRYPT`?

Comment: yeah both are not identical. So what can be the solution can you please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

> So here What i did: For encryption of existing data I used AES_ENCRYPT() method ,

That's where you went wrong.

CodeIgniter's `Encryption` class doesn't just do a naked AES encryption of the data. It takes [a lot of steps to protect against adaptive chosen-ciphertext attacks](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.1-stable/system/libraries/Encryption.php#L378-L391):

- HKDF-SHA256 is used to split your key into two keys (one for AES, the other for HMAC-SHA256).
- The data is encrypted with AES-CBC (MySQL's `AES_ENCRYPT()` only provides [ECB](https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin/)) with a random IV.
- The IV and ciphertext are authenticated with HMAC-SHA256.

They're simply incompatible with each other, and the correctly implemented one is CodeIgniter, not MySQL. You want CodeIgniter's design.

Comment: AES_ENCRYPT() supports CBC, which can be set like this:
SET @@SESSION.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';

Comment: @redsd AES-CBC is still not good enough. See https://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack/